# What is the default setting for SVM in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, libsvm

I would like to know what is the default setting for SVM of weka library?. As I know Weka wraps LIVSVM and the default parameter for [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is the rbf kernel, does this holds true for weka?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default kernel is RBF with gamma equal to 1/k. See other defaults in javadocs [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.html) or [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/LibSVM/1.0.4/weka/classifiers/functions/LibSVM.java).

NB: Weka contains its own implementation - [SMO](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html), but it also provides wrapper for libsvm, and ["LibSVM runs faster than SMO"](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/LibSVM/1.0.6.html) (note that it requires installed libsvm, see [docs](https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM)).